# How to get xquery assertion value using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have created a teststep in SOAPUI tool with two assertions namely

1. Valid HTTP Status codes Assertion and
2. XQuery Match Assertion

Now I need to print the values contained in these assertions using groovyscript.  For XQuery Assertion, I need to print the xquery expression . I tried using getToken() method.

Given below is my code

```
for(int k=0;k<tc.getTestStepCount();k++)
{
  RestTestRequestStep rr= tc.getTestStepAt(k);
  RestTestRequest rrprop=rr.getTestRequest();
  int astcount=rr.getAssertionCount();
  for(int z=0;z<astcount;z++)
    {
      WsdlMessageAssertion tassert=rr.getAssertionAt(z);
      String assertname=tassert.getName();
      log.info "Assertion Name= "+assertname
      String assertvalue=rr.getAssertionAt(z).getToken();
      log.info "Assertion Value= "+assertvalue
    }
}
```

But it is throwing the following error.

```
Fri May 22 11:11:58 IST 2015:INFO:groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.XQueryContainsAssertion.getToken() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Please suggest me which method should be used here..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getPath()` method to get the `XQuery Expression` on your assertion. Take into account that this method is specific for assertions of `XQueryContainsAssertion` class, so if you invoke in other assertion object you'll get a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException`. Also think about that with your code you're casting each testStep in your testCase to `RestTestRequestStep` (`RestTestRequestStep rr= tc.getTestStepAt(k);`) and the groovy `testStep` itself its part of the testCase and cannot be cast to this type, so better use `def` for the object to avoid cast errors.

So taking all this stuff in account considering that you only want to apply your code for this kind of assertions you could have something as:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.XQueryContainsAssertion

def tc = testRunner.testCase
for(int k=0;k<tc.getTestStepCount();k++)
{
  def rr= tc.getTestStepAt(k)
  // check that the testStep really contains assertions (it's not a groovy TestStep for example)
  if(rr.metaClass.respondsTo(rr,"getAssertionCount")){
      int astcount=rr.getAssertionCount()
      for(int z=0;z<astcount;z++)
        {
          def tassert=rr.getAssertionAt(z)
          String assertname=tassert.getName()
          log.info "Assertion Name= "+assertname
          // check the assert it's a XqueryContainsAssertion
          if(tassert instanceof XQueryContainsAssertion){
            String assertvalue=tassert.getPath()
            log.info "Assertion Value= "+assertvalue
          }
        }
  }
}
```

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT**

If you want to get also the `http status codes` you can use the property `codes` in your assertion of type [`ValidHttpStatusCodesAssertion`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/security/assertion/ValidHttpStatusCodesAssertion.html), I modify the previous code to take in account the both types of assertions:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.XQueryContainsAssertion
import com.eviware.soapui.security.assertion.ValidHttpStatusCodesAssertion

def tc = testRunner.testCase
for(int k=0;k<tc.getTestStepCount();k++)
{
  def rr= tc.getTestStepAt(k)
  // check that the testStep really contains assertions (it's not a groovy TestStep for example)
  if(rr.metaClass.respondsTo(rr,"getAssertionCount")){
      int astcount=rr.getAssertionCount()
      for(int z=0;z<astcount;z++)
        {
          def tassert=rr.getAssertionAt(z)
          String assertname=tassert.getName()
          log.info "Assertion Name= "+assertname
          // check the assert it's a XqueryContainsAssertion
          if(tassert instanceof XQueryContainsAssertion){
            String assertvalue=tassert.getPath()
            log.info "Assertion Value= "+assertvalue
          }else if(tassert instanceof ValidHttpStatusCodesAssertion){
            String assertvalue=tassert.codes
            log.info "Http status codes= "+assertvalue
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: @ArachselviSivakumar nice to help you `:)`

Comment: @ albciff I am adding a Valid Http Status Code Assertion to a teststep ,with value "200". I am trying to get that value "200" using groovy script. but I don't know which method to be used exactly.. I tried using getConfiguration() method. But i couldn't get that value. So can you please help me ?

Comment: @ArachselviSivakumar I add the case to the answer, take a look on it. Hope it helps `:)`